# How do I convert a Google Doc for alternate cloud storage, with revision history intact, to a openable document in Dropbox

Tags: dropbox, google-docs, word-processor

Is there a way to do this easily? Keep version history of the document on the document? As a .gdoc or .whatever-format or am I resigned in having to download, separately, all the revisions made in the past on said document?

For context: I have a document I've been editing and revising over the years for my own medical history and list of meds, history, etc. etc. and have been using Google Docs to do this, because it was convenient and I didn't have to pay for Microsoft Office and additionally install a good word processor on my PC. Now recently I've purchased Dropbox Personal for cloud storage needs.

I want to do the following: Take the Google Doc and save it as a .gdoc (which isn't an option in the File menu??) and take it over to Dropbox's Vault as an editable hardcopy with its revisions history in tact.

Otherwise, what I have done (before I even comprehended revision history was a thing) is just copy pasted its current version, onto a new .gdoc in Dropbox Vault.

So, is that possible? And if so, how and as easily (lazily) as I possibly can? Also, is this even the right place to ask for this? Apologies if it isn't. I didn't see much else about this specific issue anywhere... (also lazy)

Thanks!

EDIT:

I am by no means a coder in any sense. I'm a full time elderly caretaker and I'm just a guy with a specific, niche?, technical, problem and thought this was the first place to ask without having to go through tech support w/ Google chat etc. And it might also help some other people that like seeing how their documents have changed over the years, history fans etc. At the end of the day it's a programming/coding issue, that could be resolved someway some how... Right?

If I can add pictures here for context, LMK.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

1. The .gdoc file format is only accessible via Google Docs which is on web. Downloading the file to your *local storage* means you would have to access it on your device using your *local apps (word editor)* such as Microsoft Office,Libre Office, etc.(other word editor apps on desktop application level) which is why the .gdoc format is not available when you download. This is also why you won't be able to have it openable from your dropbox.
2. The version/revision history on Google Docs is intact only to that specific file with that unique ID. So when you download the file, the version history won't be available to the physically downloaded file which is stored on web or even when you make a copy of it, the version history does not get copied, therefore that won't be an option too.

It looks like you'll have to stick to manually copying or making a backup of  the current version of the file before editing, since the version history is only kept for a period of 30 days or the last 100 versions, unless manually set to **"Keep forever"** to keep a version forever.

- Google drive version history: https://googledrivepro.com/google-drive-version-history/